# Почему выборка в MySQL быстрее чем в MongoDB

Tags: mysql, база-данных, mongodb

Подумываем о том, чтобы перенести логи с MySQL на MongoDB. В сообществе говорят что для таких задач монго неплохо подходит - быстрая скорость записи и быстрая обработка запросов.

Решили проверить перед переходом на MongoDB скорость записи и выборки опытным путем по сравнению с MySQL. Нам важно чтобы логи можно было фильтровать по 4-6 параметрам

Обе БД находятся на одной машине.

**MySQL схема:**

- id *INT*
- response *ENUM*
- type_id *INT* (FK)
- status_id *INT* (FK)

Пример строки:
**|1|CATCH|3|4|**

**MongoDB схема:**

- _id *ObjectId*
- response *STRING*
- data *STRING*
- type *STRING*
- status *STRING*

Пример документа: **|blabla|CATCH|VISIT|PROCESSING|**

В каждую БД было добавлено по 4 млн записей. Процесс записи в MongoDB был быстрее примерно в 2 раза.

В каждой БД были добавлены одиночные индексы по перечисленным ключевым полям.

Результат тестирования запросов следующий (LIMIT 10000):

- По type(сек) MongoDB: 0.11 MySQL 0.32
- По type+status(сек) MongoDB: 5.5 MySQL 0.40
- По type+status(сек) MongoDB: 4.7 MySQL 0.5

Кеш запросов в MySQL был выключен.
Вопрос: Почему выборка в MySQL произошла быстрее чем в MongoDB, хотя сообщество говорит обратное?

Comment: так и есть. запись в монго - быстрее, чтение - на том же уровне или медленнее. можете посмотреть статью на хабре - https://habr.com/post/87620/

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis спасибо за ссылку. Меня смутило, что от 2-х условий выборки монго прям сильно медленнее работает - разница в 10 раз...

Comment: вероятно потому что не были созданы множественные индексы , а только одиночные

Comment: типовое применение БД в 80% применений - это чтение. это надо просто запомнить.  об этом говорит сообщество, какое не скажу, секретики... )))